# Spring Batch Application Died for No Reason

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have one Spring Batch Application that is intermittenly died for no reason. It is started and hang at unknown status. From logs, seems like it is still processing records but somehow it stopped. No error message printed. If I restarted jar files, it works again and for some amount of time it is stopped again, no error or anything.

Previously, it got error of SQL Time Out. I'm wondering if its because of that the spring batch is hung.

It is also not because of out of memory, because I don't find any error files printed outside jars.

This is first time I'm using spring batch, and I respect any of your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to make a thread dump using `jstack` utility from JDK. Maybe a deadlock is occurred

Comment: okay, I'll try first